# Dropdown holds its selection after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I want my dropdown list to return to its first value after page refresh.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div>
            <li><label>Type2</label>
            <select id="sss">
                <option selected id="one1">ONE</option>
                <option id="two2">TWO</option>
            </select><br></li>
    </div>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('sss').selectedIndex=0
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works in Firefox but not in IE10. Can anybody please help?

Comment: Do you have jQuery? or are you doing this with only raw javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I had to force the script to run after the page is loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function loaded() {document.getElementById('sss').selectedIndex=0;}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loaded()">
    <div>
            <li><label>Type2</label>
            <select id="sss">
                <option id="one1" SELECTED>ONE</option>
                <option id="two2">TWO</option>
            </select><br></li>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```